# php how to save an fpdi object as a pdf file

Tags: php, file, pdf, tcpdf, fpdi

I'm using fpdi for creating/editing my pdfs, and was wondering how to save the output(essentially "save as" a pdf file) to the local harddrive?  Example:

```
$pdf = new FPDI();
$pdf->setSourceFile("test.pdf");
$page= $pdf->importPage(1);
$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->useTemplate($page);

$pdf->Output();  // So instead of outputting to browser, how to save file as a pdf?
```

Basically instead of outputting the fpdi object, how do i save it as a pdf file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define an output file in the output function.

```
$filename="/home/user/public_html/test.pdf";
$pdf->Output($filename,'F');
```

Answer (score 2):

Using FPDF:

```
$pdfData = $pdf->Output('nameOfFile.php','F') //Save as pdf file (Make sure you have permisions)
$pdfData = $pdf->Output('nameOfFile.php','S') //Return the document as string
```

Answer (score 0):

FPDI is a extension for [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/), so you can get the PDF data as a string:

```
$pdfData = $pdf->Output('', 'S')
```

You can then save this to disk in any way you want.

Comment: i c...but anyway to save it as a pdf with all the template information intact?

Comment: Why would you waste time and memory and assign this data to a variable that you're never going to use other than to save it to a file?